# Roots of a family of 4-parameter polynomials

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, differential-calculus

Let $k, \ell, p$ and $q$ be positive integers, with $q>p>1$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Let $f(x)$ the polynomial given by 
$$
f(x)=x^q-kx^{q-p}-\ell.
$$
This polynomial is related to a family of two-parameters binary sequences.

Now, I would like to prove that $f$ has a dominant root and that all the roots are simples. I was able to solve for some particular cases (e.g., $p=2$ and $k=q=1$).

Someone has some suggestion for proving this, in the general case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $q$ and $p$ are both divisible by 3, then with each root $\theta$ there are roots $e^{2\pi i/3}\theta$ and $e^{-2\pi i/3}\theta$, which of them is "dominant"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact, I forgot to say that, clearly, $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

Comment: That assumption seems to render "$f$ is not an even function" redundant, no?

Comment: @user44191 yes, I modified now.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, you are right. I forgot to include that p and q are coprime.

Comment: "dominant" = "of the largest absolute value" or "of the smallest absolute value" (or anything else)?

Comment: Sorry I keep adding and deleting an answer, but I keep noticing small different criteria that I think I missed. I do think that your claim of simple roots is incorrect; integer solutions to $\ell^p = \frac{(q - p)^{q - p} k^q p^p}{q^q}$ for a given even $p$, odd $q$ will imply a double root.

Comment: For an example: $x^5 - 15x^3 - 162$ has a double root at $-3$.